# How do I trigger Java Selenium Tests post deployment in VSTS

Tags: java, selenium, deployment, automated-tests, azure-devops

We are generating a Web Service for deployment to Azure. This includes four pipeline stages for Dev, Test, Full UAT and production. On initial deployment to Dev I want to perform a set of Selenium smoke tests. Then when deployed to UAT, a full set of automated tests should be triggered.

Our test team are happier using Selenium through its Java route. After a couple of days it became clear that the process was to generate a UI agent (really important to anyone who hasn't done this yet, as ChromeDriver does run without a session, but will just hang, making you think it must be close to running), assign a SELENIUM_TEST agent property, and set this flag as a build dependency (this helps it to find the correct agent), and ensure that you set the required java and maven variables in the VSTS settings (apart from the path), rather than the local machine environment. Finally to use the clean, update and -X parameters to force the environment to be configured as part of the test process.

Now I have the problem of how do I trigger these tests from the deployment pipeline. I have searched and found articles on a large number sites and cant find anything on how this may be achieved using the Maven Java Selenium combination.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the problem for you to "trigger a build task" ? And how do you want to trigger the test in VSTS release pipeline, can you explain more details and how you configured the tasks?

Comment: Hi Marina, The problem is synchronisation of test. I wish to deploy the WebApp to a test slot and after deployment trigger testing. The idea being to automate smoke tests against every build. It appears that selenium tests can do this using c# but does not indicate how this can be achieved using java based selenium tests.

Comment: Then you can refer this blog http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1403/continuous-testing-java-using-vsts-selenium, or the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/continuous-test-java?view=vsts.

Comment: Hi Marina, Many thanks for your response. I referred to the second article to get the test running in its own CI pipeline, and I think I have a rather untidy way of translating that into a deployment pipeline. I am now looking at the first article to see if that gives me a neater solution. Many thanks. Really appreciate you guys trying to help me through this.

Comment: I added it as an answer. Since it has works for you, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Comment: Hi Marina, whilst it was helpful I couldn't see quite how the test code was being transferred into the web-app deployment pipeline. I have slightly swapped it round, and still haven't got a full answer, but am close now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For build and deploy Java Selenium Tests in VSTS, you can refer the document [Testing Java applications with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/continuous-test-java?view=vsts) for detail steps:

[image]

[image]

Besides, you can also refer the blog [Continuous Testing of a Java Web App in VSTS using Selenium](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1403/continuous-testing-java-using-vsts-selenium) for build and deploy Java Web App in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not posting this as a full answer, but I wanted to respond to the kind input from Michele and Marina. I am not sure that there isn't a better way of approaching this but with the assistance of both I was able to at least get closer to an answer. I did prepare images, but apparently you need a reputation to do so.

So this is what I actually ended up doing.

Step 1 – the MVC web app was generated and appropriate deployment slots set up to receive the web build artefacts.

Step 2 – Created a CI process purely to generate code I could deploy into the WebApp CD pipeline.

Step 3 – Generated an empty “Smoke Test” environment in the WebApp Deployment pipeline, and added the new Artefact from step 1 into this.

Configured the Smoke Tests item

- Configured it to only receive the _AutoTest-CI artefact
- Set it to use the “default” pipeline
- Added the “Demand” that specifies the machine configured for Selenium tests.
- Added the Maven task, and pointed it at the Maven POM

At this stage it succeeded to run through the configured tests. The Maven deployment step seems to have the idea that it can generate test results, but the output gives warnings that no test results were generated. It will generate the output, and reports a success or failure, so this is a semi-success. The missing last piece is to report the full test results, which I have yet to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger the Tasks inside of an Environment by configuring the Triggers with this tools in the Release management UI.

[image: release]

If the trigger contitions are met the process will start automatically. Inside of your process you can do whatever Task you need.

#### Reference

[Microsoft VSTS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts)

Comment: Thanks Michele for your speedy response. The issue I have is not the ability to generate a deployment step, but to trigger a build task. I can create a Maven task as a step in a deployment phase, but I would need the ability to get sources as part of that and I don't see that as an option in the available tasks.

Comment: I am figuring that this is doable, as Selenium is a much favoured tool, I just haven't found a documented case of how to achieve it in a deployment pipeline. Again - many thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but in a Release process your input are build artifacts, not sources. In a Build process your input is source code.

Comment: However probably I misunterstood your needs and I was more focused on the _have the problem of how do I trigger these tests from the deployment pipeline_ part.

Comment: Hi Michele, I am not an automated test expert, but am aware that the c# selenium build process generates aretefacts that can be run. As far as I have been able to determine this is not the case for java based tests. So I can run the tests as a CI process, but need to do this from a CD pipeline so that I can be sure that the tests are running after the web app has been deployed. Alternatively I need to trigger the CI for the tests from this alternate CD pipeline.